Connecting to local SQL Server Express from Docker
I've created a default ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API project with enabled docker. Now I want to access a SQL Server Express instance on my local machine.
If I run the created project in IIS, I can do it (I use EF), but when I launch it via Docker, I get the following error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)'

My initial connection string (that works if I launch application on IIS) is
Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CoreDb;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=False

As I understand, the issue is related to open ports.
My docker file (generated by default) is:
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["APP/APP.csproj", "APP/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./APP/APP.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/APP"
RUN dotnet build "./APP.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./APP.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "APP.dll"]

I've tried changing data source in the connection string to '%MY_IP,1433%':
Data Source=%MY_IP%,1433\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CoreDb;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=False

but it didn't help, I think some mapping should be added into docker file, but not sure how yet
UPDATE:
connection strings with Data Source like Data Source=host.docker.local\\SQLEXPRESS... or Data Source=host.docker.internal\\SQLEXPRESS... also didn't help

you probably need docker.host.local

@siggemannen, if you mean specifying connection string like: Data Source=host.docker.local\\..., then it doesn't work (I also tried Data Source=host.docker.internal\\... )

yeah, whatever it is that points to your local computer. Do you get same error or another one?

@siggemannen, yes, the error is the same as before

note: yeah, whatever it is that points to your local computer, i didn't configure any source like host.docker.internal/local anywhere, so I assume it's configured by default

Connect to database using SQL Server Management Studio.  The login window will show the correct instance of the Server to use in you connection string.  Why do you have the period and two backslashes?  Should be only one backslash Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;

I copied this connection string from Server Explorer in Visual Studio which generates the same connection string as in SSMS. As I wrote above, the connection string itself is valid (I can connect to it from IIS), the problem happens only when I'm trying to connect to this database from docker

Depending on the version SQL Server Express often isn't even listening on TCP/IP ports by default. Have you gone into SQL Server Configuration Manager to enable the TCP/IP protocol for the SQLEXPRESS instance? If you make any changes in here be sure to restart both the SQLEXPRESS instance as well as the SQL Browser service (which is reposible for resolving instance names to ports). Then host.docker.internal\SQLEXPRESS should work for you.

Also note that Integrated Security=true isn't likely to work for you since the Docker container is Linux-based and doesn't have Kerberos authentication configured by default. i.e.: try using SQL Logon authentication with User ID and Password credentials for a valid logon that you've created in the SQLEXPRESS instance.
